# Problems compiling PHP make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1

Tags: mac-osx, php-fpm

Here is the message I am getting:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_iconv_close", referenced from:
      _zif_iconv_substr in iconv.o
      _zif_iconv_mime_encode in iconv.o
      _php_iconv_string in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_strlen in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_strpos in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_mime_decode in iconv.o
      _php_iconv_stream_filter_cleanup in iconv.o
      ...
  "_iconv_open", referenced from:
      _zif_iconv_substr in iconv.o
      _zif_iconv_mime_encode in iconv.o
      _php_iconv_string in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_strlen in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_strpos in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_mime_decode in iconv.o
      _php_iconv_stream_filter_factory_create in iconv.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
```

Also I have been receiving allot of warnings while I was compiling with Make.

e.g:

```
zend_operators.c:2171:34: warning: 
  'finite' is deprecated: first deprecated in OS X 10.9
  [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                    } else if (dval1 == dval2 && !zend_finite(dval1)) {

zend_compile.c:4010:9: warning: assigning
  to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers
  [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    lcname = hash_key->arKey;
           ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

 'unsigned char *' converts between pointers to integer types with
  different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
                                    sc = YYCURSOR;
                                       ^
Zend/zend_ini_scanner.l:479:12: warning: assigning to 'unsigned char *' from
  'char *' converts between pointers to integer types with different sign
  [-Wpointer-sign]
            YYCURSOR = sc;
```

They are many more of those.

Here is my commands:

```
./configure --enable-fpm --with-pdo-mysql --with-mcrypt --with-zlib --with-openssl --with-curl

make
```

I am login in as root.

Here are more details:

PHP-5.5.13
Mac OS X 10.9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like PHP cannot find the symbolds because iconv renamed them.

See the following link for details:

[SuperUser Answer by fidell](https://superuser.com/questions/394219/compiling-php-on-os-x-iconv-works-only-if-forced-to-64-bit)

qoute:

> The MacPorts iconv library renames the symbols to _libiconv_open and _libiconv_close. That's why PHP couldn't find them,... Run nm /opt/local/lib/libiconv.dylib vs nm /usr/lib/libiconv.dylib (in 10.7.3).

Comment: What about all these warnings? Should I worry about them? They are many of them.

Comment: It depends, if you can fix them, do it, but thats not allways possible and you might need to accept them.

However there might be a possibility there is still something else wrong, which creates the large amount of warnings.

Comment: I just uninstalled everything from Mac Port and it worked.

Comment: For some reason (nm /opt/local/lib/libiconv.dylib vs nm /usr/lib/libiconv.dylib) did not work for me. But uninstalling everything worked from Mac Port.